# Was my XMR lost or stolen?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, security

I installed GUI wallet on windows 10 about 18 months ago and daemon wouldn’t start on its own.
After restarting it manually every time, it synchronized and wallet was working somehow OK. I
received XMR only, never sent any. Hash of the downloaded GUI file was checked.

Just recently, I installed GUI wallet on second PC, using same Ledger Nano S with the same mnemonics
and after lengthy synchronization, it showed 0.000 balance. I reinstalled GUI wallet and after syncing,
zero balance again. Hash of the downloaded file was checked as well. Sending address shows same as on the first wallet.

So I checked the balance on the first computer and there was still proper balance displayed. Then I
upgraded to the latest version of GUI wallet and after syncing, it shows zero balance as well. The sending address again shows same as on the first wallet.
I am 100% sure that mnemonics was not compromised and my Bitcoin and Cardano is still there.

I am doing something wrong or my XMR was stolen on wallet level. If so, there must be major
weakness in GUI wallet and in that case I am done with Monero for good! Used to be my favorite crypto.

Any help with solving this problem would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please try the guide I linked.

Answer (score 0):

To get your wallet to display the correct balance, click "Settings", "Info", then look for the line "Wallet restore height" and click the "(Change)" link to the right of the number.  Following the format YYYY-MM-DD, enter a date that is before the time your transactions were made and click the Ok button.  Then wait a while for everything to fully resynch.  It should update to the correct balance.